# What is the best way to make a copy of an InputStream in java

Tags: java, copy, inputstream

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to make a deep copy of an InputStream in Java ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4064211/how-to-make-a-deep-copy-of-an-inputstream-in-java)

I have an InputStream object and I want to make a copy of it. What is the best way to do this?

The data is not coming from a file but as the payload of a http form being sent from a web page, I am using the Apache Commons FileUpload lib, my code which gives me the InputStream looks like this: ...

```
InputStream imageStream = null;

boolean isMultipart = ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request);
        FileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
        ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
        List items = new ArrayList();

        items = upload.parseRequest(request);
        Iterator iter = items.iterator();
        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            FileItem item = (FileItem) iter.next();
            if (item.isFormField()) { // this is subject Id
                if (item.getFieldName().equals("subId")) {
                    subId = Integer.parseInt(item.getString());
                    System.out.println("SubId: " + subId);
                }
            } else {
                imageStream = item.getInputStream();

            }
        }
```

What is the best way to get a duplicate/copy of imageStream?

Comment: What do you mean by duplicate copy? You can read several times the input stream if that is what you want.

Comment: @MarvinLabs - sorry I guess "duplicate copy" is a tautology

Answer (score 5):

If you want to be able to read the stream again, I think your best option is to wrap the `InputStream` in a `BufferedInputStream`, and then use the `BufferedInputStream` `mark()` and `reset()` methods. The `InputStream` you have will probably not support them directly, since as far as I understood it receives data from the web.

Answer (score 1):

The best way of "copying" your input stream is to use commons-io. Since you're using commons fileupload alread, that additional dependency won't hurt:

http://commons.apache.org/io/

Be aware though, that you cannot really "copy" a stream. You can only "consume" it (and then maybe store the contents in memory, if you want that)